# How to access pgRouting Layers via script

Tags: qgis-plugins, pgrouting

I would like to provide input to the pgRouting Layers through a script.

The scenario is as follows:

I have a bunch of points whereof every point is representing a starting point and I have another bunch of points representing destinations.

Each of the start points need to be routed to every destination point (shortest path) and I want to retrieve the length of the route (distance), and if possible the travel time.

I can iterate over the start, and destination points, but how do I get it done that I feed the x/y data to pgRouting Layers and extract the required information from the return values?

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to write a PostgreSQL stored function to do that and use DbManager Plugin to plot the output of the stored function.

Comment: Alright, do you have any link for a little tutorial on how to do this? Thank you!